# file default editor is changed `Eclipse`

Tags: windows, eclipse, editor, open-with

I have an opened project in `Eclipse`. I have some special extensions like `*.VW`,`*.RW` and many. 
If I double click those files in `Eclipse`, it will automatically open in default `eclipse text editor`.

> Problem:  Unfortunately, I have opened `*.RW` file with `Notepad` (via
>   file system).

Now, if I double click those files in `Eclipse`, it is getting opened in `Notepad` only `:(`. How do I reset the default editor?

Thanks

Comment: similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15564065/changing-default-xml-editor-in-eclipse

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right click and `Open with ...` should the opening behaviour in eclipse. Furthermore you can set the behaviour in `Preferences -> General -> Editors -> File Associations`.