# Changing default XML editor in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, xml-editor

Eclipse hangs when [working with XML's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13145556/eclipse-hangs-when-dealing-with-xmls-going-to-or-from-them-cpu-disk-spike) ..

the default editor is too slow and gives lot problem

I read, it works fine if we change the editor so how to remove existing editor ??

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can customize them: **Window -> Preferences -> General -> Editors -> File Associations**

There, you'll have to either select a file extension,
or add one to the list and choose what editor eclipse should use
to open it with whenever it's needed.

Answer (score 3):

To just open the file once,
Right Click - Open With


To change association,
Windows - Preferences - General - Editors - File Associations